# Mysql - order by certain strings

Tags: mysql

I have a players table. Each player has a position which is either goalkeeper, defender, midfielder or forward. I want to return all players, with forwards first, then midfielders, then defenders, then goalkeepers. Obviously, if I do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  'Player' 
ORDER BY position
```

the defenders will be returned first....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Player 
ORDER BY find_in_set(position,'forward,midfielder,defender,goalkeeper')
```

Answer (score 3):

Either—

- Use `FIELD()` as [suggested by @Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18927129), however note that this will not scale well with larger tables (as a filesort must be performed on the calculated function result for each record).
- Make `position` an `ENUM`:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE Player
    MODIFY position ENUM('forward','midfielder','defender','goalkeeper');
  ```

  Then the results of your existing query will be sorted accordingly:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM Player ORDER BY position;
  ```

  This is because, as documented under [The `ENUM` Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/enum.html#enum-sorting):

  > #### Sorting
  >
  > `ENUM` values are sorted based on their index numbers, which depend on the order in which the enumeration members were listed in the column specification.
- Make a table to hold the position ordering:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE position_order (
    position VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
    priority TINYINT UNSIGNED
  );

  INSERT INTO position_order
    (position, priority)
  VALUES
    ('forward'   , 1),
    ('midfielder', 2),
    ('defender'  , 3),
    ('goalkeeper', 4)
  ;

  ALTER TABLE Player
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (position) REFERENCES position_order (position);
  ```

  Then the results of your query can be sorted by joining the tables and sorting on the new `priority` column:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM Player JOIN position_order USING (position) ORDER BY priority;
  ```

Note that you may wish to read Chris Komlenic's article [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) before deciding which approach to take.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CASE statement in the ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Player 
ORDER BY CASE Position WHEN "forward" THEN 1
                       WHEN "defender" THEN 2
                       WHEN "midfielder" THEN 3
                       WHEN "goalkeeper" THEN 4 END ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a804a/17)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Player 
ORDER BY FIELD(position,'forward', 'midfielder', 'defender', 'goalkeeper')
```